# How to service HTTP requests on web server

Tags: objective-c, http

Alright. I know this may draw some heat as "not good question"/etc., but I haven't found anywhere describing the process in particular (all the resources I've found describe the client-side requesting, not the server-side responses).

I'm going to be working on writing an iOS app in the next coming months necessitating the use of a web server. There are many resources on how to set these up, get them a static IP, etc. but I haven't found any clear ones (and by clear, I mean intelligible by someone not already experienced in it) on how to write a program for such a server that actually responds to the HTTP or client request.

Suppose I have a dummy app and web server combo where the app posts an HTTP request for the time. How would I write an app for the server to bounce the time back when the request comes in? Ideally, I'd like to write this in Objective-C as it's the language I've had the most experience in (whether forced or by choice).

Again, I apologize if it isn't a good question or very clear - I just haven't found any resources that are able to give me much of a place to start.

Comment: We build an easy-to-use server platform for Objective-C: http://objective-cloud.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question could probably be described as 'too broad', but I will give it a shot anyway. Disclaimer: I haven't written much server-side code but I have been programming in objc for years now.

The reason you haven't found (m)any resources to help you do what you want to do is because Objective-C is rarely used for writing server-side code. Exactly why that is the case is no doubt a long story, but essentially the answer is because many of the dominant technologies out there (PHP, Python, C#, Java, to name only the prevailing languages) have feaures and associated frameworks that are better suited for that purpose.

In other words, although I can doubltless be done, you are probably better off using something other than Objective-C for the task because:

1. You will have many more resources available to help you get your job done.
2. You will have a much larger community that you can query for assistance when (not if) you encounter an obstacle.
3. You will not have to do many things the hard way because there will be existing tools to make it easier.

Comment: Thank you for tackling such a question anyway. Do you have any links or resources toward doing such activities in Java, for example? I know a fair amount of Java, it's just Objective-C that happens to be what I'm 'in practice' with as of late (worst comes to worst, I have reference materials). It just seems that most tuts/resources are tailored towards client-side JSONs and HTTP requests and I haven't been able to find any dealing with how the server goes about responding to such requests.

Comment: No problem. I am not a Java dev so I can't help you there, but I'm sure that searching for the keywords java server tutorial will produce something useful. Just so you know, requests for links to resources are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend you to use PHP as the server-side programming language.

Some mounths ago I was in the same situation as you. We have planned to write a app (Android) which loads some data from a webserver. I've never programmed server-side code till the beginning of the project. So it was quiet interessting and new for me.

We have choosen PHP as the server-side language.

All I can say is, that it was really easy to learn and write your first scripts to get a response to a HTTP-Request. Also the usage of MySQL as the database is really easy and it works fine with PHP.

PHP is a standard. You can find a huge amount of documentation and examples. And of course tutorials and good books ... ;)

Comment: Always good to have someone around who is/was in the same boat. Do you have any basic tutorials for how to handle requests (i.e. a "server hello world")?